# Should i use object or css with react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i'm currently working on a small chat app , using reactJS an materialUI component library.

Material UI use a lot of objet to describe the style of our element (like the "sx" props).

I was wondering if i still should use css or shouhd i put my css into my component as an object (more like a vue component). here is an example with an object :

```js
    import React from 'react'
import CameraAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CameraAlt'

const AvatarForm = ({setAvatar}) => {

  return (
    <Box sx={sx}>
        <label htmlFor="photo">
          <CameraAltIcon />
        </label>
        <input 
          type="file" accept="image/*" 
          id="photo"
          onChange={ e => setAvatar(e.target.files[0])}
          style={{display: "none"}}
        />
    </Box>
  )
}
    
export default AvatarForm


const sx = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  textAlign: "center",
}
```

Is it a good practice ? and why ?

Comment: Use CSS-in-JS: like styled-components or emotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-use-inline-styles) says that, whilst using inline-styles is supported, using standard css classes in generally better for performance.

Thus, in your situation I would recommend sticking to the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

if you prefer your css inside your js files, there is a new way of using it all together which called [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). Its really nice and have cool features.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll check it out !